# Have any libraries implemented UITextInputDelegate for Rich Text editing on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, rich-text-editor

I'm looking for a rich text editor for the iPad.  It appears that this was nearly impossible until iPhone OS 3.2 which included the [UITextInput protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but that still leaves developers a long way from a functioning editor.

The OMNI Framework has started on a text editor (search google for 'omnigroup texteditor'), but it's more of a proof-of-concept.

Does anyone know of an open source or paid library with a complete implementation of UITextInputDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor/